# Saving users total entries on form submit

Tags: php, cookies

Here is my code right now for when the submit button is pressed:

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Amsterdam");
$timestamp = time();
$date = strtoupper(date("d/M/Y H:i"));
mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO EnteredTickets (Ticket, Person) VALUES ('$ticketno', '$fullname')");
mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE SoldTickets SET Redeemed=1 WHERE Ticket = '$ticketno' LIMIT 1");
mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO ActivityLog (Type, Ticket, Date, Timestamp, Othername) VALUES (3, '$ticketno', '$date', $timestamp, '$fullname')");

echo '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
<strong>Congratulations!</strong><br> You have succesfully been entered into the current lottery!<br />
<center><strong>Entry details</strong><br />
Name: '.$fullname.'<br />
Ticket Number: '.$ticketno.'                                                    
</div>';
```

How would I go about saving the users total entries to the competition (Preferable without use of the DB, maybe with cookies)

Then I would echo it to where I wish to place the "Your Entries".
Also how would I go about removing all users entries on a certain date, so when the competition ends it will say "0" in "Your entries" again!

Comment: SELECT (Ticket, Person) FROM 'table_name' WHERE Person='$fullname'  - this will select all the rows in your database with that person's name attached. Then you can count the results either through mysql or php. You don't need to store any additional data.

Comment: Better yet, SELECT COUNT (Person) FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE Person='$fullname' - that will give you the count directly.

Comment: How would I go about the webpage knowing the user is EG John Doe instead of Other Name? And only shows John Does entires at the start of webpage load?

As right now there is nothing in place that tells the server what client is currently on the webpage.

Comment: If there's nothing that saves the user's information, how did you plan to make a page with "Your Entries" ?

Comment: I initially planned to store it in a COOKIE or SESSION? However they do write their name in the form...

http://i.imgur.com/hmsO3Yj.png

Comment: Then why not just show it when you show the success page? Name, Ticket Number, then you could do a list of previous tickets or just a count.